# Comparing and matching a range of data with another range of data

Tags: excel, compare, match, range

Each row of 4 columns represents a set of data

```
A1 : D1  1,2,3,4

A2 : D2  4,2,1,5

A3 : D3  5,3,2,1
```

etc.

Now the column set will be compared to another column set

```
F1 : I1  4,6,3,1

F2 : I2  4,3,2,1

F3 : I3  2,3,5,1
```

The set that matches to the other column set will be marked red. So in the example `F2:I2` and `F3:I3` will be marked red. They just need to contain the same numbers. The order is not important but all numbers should match.

I thought of using conditional statements but can't seem to find a way to compare and match sets of range to other sets of range.

As an alternative, I thought of adding all the columns `=A1&" "&A2&" "&A3&" " &A4` then sort it then match it from there but I tried sorting from left to right the sets and it doesn't seem to be sorting right if I do it all at once. The sheet will contain a large amount of rows so that will be a chore to do it 1 by 1.

So I'm out of ideas as I am not that good with excel. :(
Appreciate all the help I can get. :)
Also, I don't mind learning other languages if it makes things easier. (as long as I can import the data from an excel)

Comment: Do the columns need to match or do the rows? How does F2:I2 match to the other column sets? I am unclear as to what needs to match and or how F2:I2 and F3:I3 would meet your criteria. Are you saying the numbers in this row on the right match the numbers in any row on the left?

Comment: Yes, the numbers in the row on the right matches the numbers on the left.1 row of 4 columns is 1 combination. So A1:D1 = 1,2,3,4. So if I use what Tim Williams suggested then E1 = 4,3,2,1 combining all the data into one cell in descending order. Would do the same to the other 4 column combinations. Then match them.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a single column to match on then this should do it:

`=CONCATENATE(LARGE(A1:D1,1),":",LARGE(A1:D1,2),":",LARGE(A1:D1,3),":",LARGE(A1:D1,4))`

Then you can use the regular lookup functions such as `MATCH()`